# 'process.argv'/'process.argv.slice(1)' is not working in cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I am using **cypress with js** for the automation testing.
My current requirement is to store the command which user pass to run a script.
Let me explain it in detail:
Here is my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "e2e-headless": "cypress run --spec cypress/integration/examples/allSpec.js --browser chrome",
    "e2e": "cypress run --spec cypress/integration/examples/allSpec.js --browser chrome --headed",
    "suite": "cypress run --spec cypress/integration/examples/Suite.js --browser chrome --headed"
  },
```

User can use any script to run. if user run `npm run suite` command. I want to store this command in a variable. i.e. If I store it in `cmd` variable and print it, it should give me an output `npm run suite`

For that I tried below code in `test.js` file:

```
const scriptName = process.argv.slice(1); //with different number in argument
console.log('The script name is:' + scriptName);
```

and

```
const scriptName = process.argv; //also tried process.argv[2]
console.log('The script name is:' + scriptName);
```

But it's not giving me the expected output.
I also tried:

```
"scripts": {
  "suite": "cross-env MY_SCRIPT_NAME=cypress run --spec cypress/integration/examples/Suite.js --browser chrome --headed"
}
```

```
const scriptName = process.env.MY_SCRIPT_NAME;
console.log('The script name is: ' + scriptName);
```

`npm install --save-dev cross-env`
But it gives me an error while executing a script that command is not recogised. I can't put the screenshot of that right now, because I restore my code as it was and don't want to disturb it.
Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Well what *is* it giving you? What does the complete `process.argv` contain?

Comment: It's contains nothing @Pointy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to add a different flag to each CLI script, see [Option #4: --env](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-4---env)

```js
"scripts": {
  "e2e-headless": "cypress run --spec ... --browser chrome --env cli=e2e-headless",
  "e2e": "cypress run --spec ... --browser chrome --headed --env cli=e2e",
  "suite": "cypress run --spec ... --browser chrome --headed --env cli=suite"
}
```

then **test.js**

```js
const scriptName = Cypress.env('cli')
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer. It's working fine. But I have a concern what if I want all arguments? Right now it's just giving me a 'suite' because we store it only inside a 'Cli'. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the actual text of the script that runs, just read it from `package.json`, something like

```js
const scriptName = Cypress.env('cli')
cy.readFile('package.json')
  .its(`scripts.${scriptName}`)
  .then(cliCommand => {
    console.log(cliCommand)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. This will also help me in the future :)